# MVC Authentication redirects to login page when it shouldn't and blocks API access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have been trying to fix this issue for a long time, but it seems that no matter what I do nothing works. I have an existing MVC webpage that I wanted to apply custom user access to and this is what I have done so far:

**Current state:**

In my Global.asax I have implemented the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest so I can set my user:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported && Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        try
        {
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                <omitted for security reasons, but newUser is created here>
                HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //Ignored
        }               
    }
    HttpContext.Current.User = null;
}
```

I'm setting the user to null if the user could not be set. This is done because on my debug machine a windows user is always logged in.

On my login page I set the form ticket (I omitted all the boring validation checks):

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,user.Username,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),false,
    userData);

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

In my web.config I have the following relevant tags:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="api/LicenseApi">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Problem:**

When I go to the root of my webpage it automatically forces me to the login page at '/Account/Login', when I expect it to go to my default routing page '/' or '/Home/Index', even though the controller is tagged with [AllowAnonymous].

And when the consumers of my API tries to post data to it, I also get redirected to the /Account/Login page, and that one is also tagged with [AllowAnonymous]. However, if I test my API with fiddler, then the first call is redirected, but if I execute the call again, it goes through correctly.

I found out that if I removed the `<authentication mode="Forms">` tag from the web.config, the API reacted as it should and my index page is shown as expected.

**Question**:

What do I need to do so that any calls to my API-Post are not redirected and that my index page is the first thing visitors see when they go to my webpage instead of a login screen.

**Update (requested by steve)**
My route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "GetFile", 
        "File/{action}", 
        new {controller = "File", action = "GetFile", fileId = UrlParameter.Optional, verifyVersion = UrlParameter.Optional} );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Authentication",
        url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I tried to remove my Authentication route just to make sure if it was that one that cause the weird auto routing. Happens even if that is removed.

Comment: "I found out that if I removed the tag from the web.config". Which tag are you refereing to?

Comment: @KingoftheNorth Sorry about that, formatting error.

Comment: Try replacing this:<allow users="*"/> with this: <deny users="?" /> in configuration > system.web > authorization

Comment: did not help, Application_PostAuthenticateRequest is called and any calls to index is redirected to login. Same for API. The redirect happens on the first connection. After that I can navigate the site fine and any [Authorize] stuff is redirected fine.

Comment: What do your registered routes look like?

Comment: @Steve Added the route config to the question